# could it be that

Tags: grammaticality, clauses

I write the following sentences:

> How will the Lord return? Could it be that the Lord may knock at our doors one day and say He is the Lord Jesus, **and then we open the door to welcome Him**?

Is "*that the Lord may knock at our doors one day and say He is the Lord Jesus, and then we open the door to welcome Him*" a subordinate clause or two clauses?

If it is two clauses, then is "**and then we open the door to welcome Him**" used correctly in grammar? If it is not correct, can you tell me why?

Comment: Saying "could it be that" is fine, but you wouldn't say "may" since "could" already expresses that, making it a tautology.  You'd say "will" instead of "may."

Comment: "And then we open the door to him" isn't a subordinate clause.  It's the second item in a list of two items that *could be*, the first item being, "the Lord may knock at our doors one day and say He is the Lord Jesus."  When listing only two things, don't put a comma before "and."

Comment: If you want to make the list appear more clearly in the sentence or make the sentence easier to read, you could add a "that" between "and" and "then."

Comment: You might also add the word "in" after "Him."

Comment: If I add a "that" between "and" and "then," do I need to delete the "then"?

Comment: No, you don't need to.